# Agregar namespace o prefix elemento XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, xml

Lo que necesito agregar al body de mi WS es lo siguiente

```
<ns1:Body>
    <ns0:ExecTR xmlns="http://www.btsincusa.com/gp/" >
         <ns0:REQUEST>
             <AGENT_TRANS_TYPE_CODE>ASDF</AGENT_TRANS_TYPE_CODE><AGENT_CD>ASD</AGENT_CD> 
         </ns0:REQUEST>
    </ns0:ExecTR>
</ns1:Body>
```

Lo que me genera suds esta así

```
<ns1:Body>
    <ns0:ExecTR>
         <ns0:REQUEST>
             <AGENT_TRANS_TYPE_CODE>ASDF</AGENT_TRANS_TYPE_CODE><AGENT_CD>ASD</AGENT_CD> 
         </ns0:REQUEST>
    </ns0:ExecTR>
</ns1:Body>
```

Hay alguna forma de agregar el namespace xmlns=""?